# Android service getting terminated if I go to main home screen using intent

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have a foreground service which would start on the boot complete. Everything is working fine except if I open my app and press on the exit button the service is getting terminated. If I kill the application by task manager then there is no issue.

This is what I have written in my exit button

```
                 Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                 homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
                 homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                 startActivity(homeIntent);
                 finish();
```

Starting my service

```
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, MyService.class);
        startIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(startIntent);
```

//Service class

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
        db=new DatabaseSqlite(this);
        showNotification();
        StartThread startThread =new StartThread();
        startThread.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Previous");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Previous!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Play!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Next");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Next!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
            Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void showNotification() {

    Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
    previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
    PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            previousIntent, 0);

    Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
    playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            playIntent, 0);

    Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
    nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            nextIntent, 0);




    startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
            setNotified("Notify","Title"));

}
private Notification setNotified(String title,String text)
{

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Splash.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.icon);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,              notificationIntent, 0);
   return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           .setContentTitle(title)
           .setTicker(text)
           .setContentText(text)
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
           .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 50, 50, false))
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setOngoing(true).build();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Detroyed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Used only in case if services are bound (Bound Services).
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does the code you posted accurately show what you are running?  The code for "Starting my service" shows `MyService`.  Elsewhere, `ForegroundService` is used.  Do you have two services?  In `showNotification()`, you build the PendingIntents but they are not used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop you intent, you can do so in the onDestroy() method.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
// check for null pointer exception
    stopService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Comment: where should i add this code.? can you be more specific.?

Comment: @ MrsEd Why should i stop my service.? I want that to be there. My issue is, my service is getting terminated whenever i exit my app using home screen intent

Comment: Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                 homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
                 homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                 startActivity(homeIntent);
                 finish(); // my exit button

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specified! I did not get the question.

Do you want to close your Activity when the NotificationService is closed?
Do yo want to close your NotificationService when the Activity is Open? 
Do you want to close Activity and NotificationService the same time?

or what are you looking for? I can help, but just I need to know what you want to do.

***Some help. You can ask for more.***
You can put it in your NotificationService. It will stop the Notification when it will click in Close button. But if you want to stop the notification and dont close the Activity, you should to check the part of you code when you are launching the Intent.

```
  @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    // check for null pointer exception
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Part of this answer seems like a comment asking for more clarification (the beginning) and the rest seems to be code copied directly from the already existing answer. (The explanation's good though!) If you copy code from another answer *please* give attribution, and please don't comment in answers. Once you get 50 reputation you'll be able to comment everywhere.